# Installing Minion Pro on Windows

Tags: fonts, installing, windows

I have been searching on the Internet but so far there is no guide that works for me.

I tried [the one from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/),
but there I have to run commands, and install the LCDF Typetools (which aren't available for Windows?).

As far as I know many people use the Minion font. Is there some easy guide out there to help me install them?

Comment: use xetex or xelatex. xe(la)tex allows you to use fonts installed on your system in your (la)tex document.

Comment: @Mica: Now I saw you answered the same as I did before me. If you're willing to write an answer, I'd be happy to delete mine.

Comment: i have the same problem with minio pro on windows 10, if youhave a solution please help me
Thinks

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install on windows (with MikTeX 2.8), using the instructions with the CTAN package. I don't remember the details, but it wasn't hard. I have the cygwin unix emulation environment installed, but I don't recall if it was necessary to use it.

**More details:**

1. `kpsewhich`: 
   use the miktex settings tool (probably best to use the `(admin)` version) to add
   a local root directory (eg., `C:\miktexlocal\`), and use this as the local path.
2. LCDF typetools for windows: as is mentioned on the LCDF website, you can get unofficial win32 binaries from ftp://akagi.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/pub/TeX/win32/
3. Making directories, copying files, moving files, etc: you can do all of this through windows explorer.
4. Adding a line to `updmap.cfg`: Use the command `initexmf --admin --edit-config-file updmap`

Comment: I really cannot get it to work. Ill point out where exactly.

1 LCDF Typetools (there is no windows version of this? how to install?

2 Commands like:  $ kpsexpand '$TEXMFLOCAL'

How to execute them?

Comment: I added a few more details.

Comment: Thx again for the help. I even used this tutorial now:http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=8415&hilit=minion

But i still cant get it to work =(

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use Xe(La)TeX, and have Adobe Reader (not Acrobat), you can install Minion Pro as an OTF fonts from `$READER_INSTALL_DIR\Resource\Font`.

Comment: I would prefer not using Xe(La)TeX. Or aint that a option?

Answer (score 1):

I converted the fonts from Linux format to Windows format using the information [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45937/can-we-get-pfb-files-from-ttf-or-otf-files). After converting the fonts from Linux format I just copied those files to my Windows machine.