# Can we get .pfb files from .ttf or .otf files?

Tags: fonts

Say, I have a `font.ttf` or `font.otf` file. Is there any method by which we can get the `font.pfb` file from them? In other words, Can we convert `ttf` to `type1` fonts? If yes, somebody please tell me how or direct me to the right path.

Comment: Could you add some motivation to this? What part of your TeX based workflow raised this issue?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt Anyone who wants to use PDFLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX with a font that isn't on CTAN would need to do this...

Comment: @Canageek: Yes I know. However, the question is a little thin and could use some padding, especially as it doesn't involve TeX on first glance. In addition, the simple answer is just "use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX", so what is the reason not to use those?

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt, My experience with xelatex has not been good with some of the fonts since I struggled my way out. So I thought if I learn this conversion I can directly use them with pdflatex.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt LuaLaTeX is still buggy, and neither support Microtype. Also neither are used by scientific journals.

Comment: @Canageek: Microtype is the same by default for LuaTeX and pdfTeX, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. It has less capability, sure, but you'll only see the difference if you really poke around. Your point on journal publishing valid of course, and why I rarely use anything other than pdflatex masquerading as LaTeX.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I thought it didn't have the ability to stick punctuation out into the margin yet? Or did the fix that?

Comment: @Canageek: That's disabled by default, and only supported by pdfTeX at the moment. I think anyway. The documentation may have been updated since I last looked at it.

Comment: @Canageek - where is the problem with microtype? It works fine here. And which bugs do you encounter? Not saying that there are none, but in _my_ practice, it works just fine.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach I've not used LuaTeX: I was warned away from it on the LaTeX IRC channel as not worth it if you weren't trying to use otf fonts, as it had some unfound bugs yet. Also it doesn't support all the features of Microtype that pdfTeX does, including margin protrusion as mentioned above.

Comment: @Canageek that's just FUD. Even TeX might have unfound bugs. A lot of people are using LuaTeX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use *ttf* fonts directly with PDFLaTeX. You can generate Type1 fonts from OTF with the [LCDF type tools](http://www.lcdf.org/type/). For example the command

```
otftotfm JosefinSansStd-Light.otf
```

gives you the files `JosefinSansStd-Light.pfb` and `JosefinSansStd-Light.tfm`.

Comment: Thanks for a way out. But, unfortunately I am on windows 7. The windows binaries are not downloading properly here.

Comment: @Dr.HarishKumar They are not in your TeX distribution?

Comment: I use MiKTeX 2.9. And can you pl. tell me how to check that?

Comment: @Dr.HarishKumar It looks as if MikTeX does not provide lcdf type tools...

Comment: Sorry, I thought PDFTeX only supported Type 1, not ttf?

Comment: @Canageek no, PDFTeX supports TrueType fonts. For example the [winfonts package on CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/winfonts) uses TrueType fonts.

Comment: Huh, so the only advantage of XeTeX is otf fonts? Huh, I'll have to look up how to use them with my documents.

Comment: @Canageek nobody said that XeTeXs only advatage is the otf fonts.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach I thought PDFTeX's advantage was Microtype, and XeTeXs was able to use system fonts?

Comment: @PatrickGundlach Whether texlive comes with lcdf type tools?

Comment: @Dr.HarishKumar Yes, lcdf is part of texlive

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in the [installfont](https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/installfont/wiki/Home) bash script. It automates the process of creating the font support files and installing them at the proper place. You need a *nix like environment like `cygwin` to run it. There's also a package of `fontforge` for `cygwin`, which would also solve your problem with the
LCDF type tools. Just load the font in `fontforge`, reencode it to AdobeStandardEncoding and export it to PostScript Type1 (Binary).

Comment: Thanks, Your answer was also useful. But I can choose only one answer. But I can say thanks again.