# MnSymbol doesn't change the default math font

Tags: fonts, mnsymbol

I'm working with MiKTeX 2.9. I've installed the package and I get no error whatsoever, but I keep getting Computer Modern words and numbers instead.

Note that I didn't install the `minionpro` package. Is it required?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
$123$ $Oh$ $come$ $on$ $be$ $Minion!$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, you need the font: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10626/installing-minion-pro-on-windows

Comment: @DG' I'm trying to use `mnsymbol` only. The question you've linked is about Minion Pro. I know I need the fonts for `minionpro`, but are those files required also for `mnsymbol`?

Comment: none of the bits you've shown in the math is a symbol; letters and digits are by definition *not* symbols.

Comment: As Barbara said: You need the actual font for `$123$ $Oh$ $come$ $on$ $be$ $Minion!$`. The symbols `MnSymbol` provides is listed in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that, I thought that all text between `$...$` was provided by a math typeface (as for Euler).

Comment: Maybe this tutorial can help you: http://kobi.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/patrick/pmwiki.php?n=Wiki.HOWTO-InstallMinionProInLATEXOnWindows

Comment: I have a doubt regarding installing Minion Pro and it is whether to use FontPro or CTAN procedure, also because I've read that recent Minion Pro metrics provided by Adobe Reader are not compatible with the latter. Is it a stupid question (like, they're not interchangeable) or is it worth asking (maybe in another question)?

Comment: Ok metrics seems to be no more an issue, from reading the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first sentence of the [MnSymbol manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) reads:

> MnSymbol is a font of mathematical symbols designed as companion to Adobe MinionPro, but it might also fit well to other renaissance or baroque faces.

In other words, `MnSymbol` doesn't change the default math font, it merely provides a set of matching mathematical symbols. If you want to use `Minion Pro` for letters and numbers, you must install `Minion Pro` on your system.

There are several options for doing so, depending on your LaTeX-engine. (You need to have access to the OpenType fonts in each case.)

You can use `Minion Pro` with `pdflatex`, `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` but [`MnSymbol` does not play nice with the last one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex).

**pdflatex**

This one is the most complicated. There are several good scripts and tutorials around. This one is for `MiKTeX 2.9`: [Installing Minion Pro on Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10626/installing-minion-pro-on-windows)

Here is a tutorial, which explains, how to install `Minion Pro` for MiKTeX 2.9: http://kobi.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/patrick/pmwiki.php?n=Wiki.HOWTO-InstallMinionProInLATEXOnWindows

If you succeeded use:

```
\usepackage[mathlf,footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

**XeLaTeX**

Install the OpenType font on your system and put something like this in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage[MnSymbol,quiet]{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro} 
\setmainfont[Ligatures         = {Common,TeX},
             Numbers           = {Lowercase, Proportional}, 
             SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters     = SmallCaps,
                                  Numbers     = Lowercase,
                                  Kerning     = Uppercase,
                                  LetterSpace = 5}]{Minion Pro}
```

Comment: Thank you! You have anticipated what would have been my next question, i.e., how to use MnSymbol with XeTeX / LuaTeX.